# Network throughput in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

Network throughput in Reactnative

I am developing a video streaming App using ReactNative. The App fetches the video frames in the JS layer and sending it native module to render. 
App uses the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tcp to fetch the video data over the network.

What we have found was that App is unable to fetch enough data in Android OS and where as in iOS it performs better. 
Is this known issue of the TCP/IP module in the Android platform?

Wrote the same functionality in C code and App could fetch much more data over the same network compared to JS.